# Plots in Python saving as blank images?

Tags: python, pdf, plot, save, png

I've created several plots in Python and am attempting to save them as .png files or pdfs. I'm using the following code to create after the data is input:

`plt.xlabel('Sersic Index Number', fontsize=16)`
`plt.ylabel('Number', fontsize=16)`
`plt.xticks(fontsize=14)`
`plt.yticks(fontsize=14)`

`plt.title('Voids In VIKING', fontsize=20)`

And the plot shows up great. However, whenever I use

`plt.savefig('Sersic_Voids.png')`

to save, it does so and the file shows up on my computer. For every time and filetype I use, the document is blank, without the plot, axes, or anything.

EDIT1: I'm already using the `plt.savefig()` format to save, but not having any luck. I don't have any plt.show() functions in, and each Jupiter Notebook has about two plots I'm trying to save, neither of which work. I've tried cutting half of the code into a blank workbook to save the first plot, but still trouble. The beginning is input as:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
```

Comment: are you plotting multiple figures or just a single one? Do you use any plt.show() in the code?

Comment: Must be related to image type-> uint,8 int64 etc

Answer (score 0):

To save matplotlib plots as a file in the PC. Go below way

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Now to make and see a chart, use the .plot() method with passing values to plot. For example, I'll plot simple points as

```
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 20, 40, 60, 85])
```

To add axis-labels

```
plt.xlabel('Number of people')
plt.ylabel('Total Weight')
```

To pop-up the graph call .show() method as,

```
plt.show()
```

To save the graph which you just plotted use **.savefig()** method

```
plt.savefig('weight_calculation.png')
```

weight_calculation -> filename
**You can also give the path to the directory you want to save**

Use dpi to change the resolution of figures you want to save

There few other add ons which you can use like,
**transparent, bbox_inches, and pad_inches.**
Change **bbox_inches** to change the size of outer white box around the figure